# Django ImageField Won't Upload

Tags: django, http, file-upload, django-models

I'm creating a website with Django that uses ImageFields. When I try it on the production server (using Passenger WSGI), the upload presumably fails somehow - the page returns a 404 and the file is not uploaded, and no error appears on the server log. The directory to upload to has 777 permissions. What could be stopping the upload?

Answer (score 0):

There might be many reasons but one issue I had was files size too big. Try some small image files to see if that works. Then you can narrow down the issue.

Comment: I tried with a small image file and it still did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide your models and settings? Probably you get MEDIA_URL configured wrong.

Comment: I'm fairly sure MEDIA_URL is configured correctly, or at least that's not the issue, because the files aren't even uploading. MEDIA_URL is only for finding them on the server to download - when people had it misconfigured, they would only have issues when trying to view the image after it successfully updated.